# Mongoose Model is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Linking my app to database utilizing mongoose I constantly get an error:

app.js (server):

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodedb', { useNewUrlParser: true });
let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to MongoDB'));

db.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));

const app = express();

let Article = require('./models/article');

const path = require('path');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

//create routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Acticle.find({}, (err, articles) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Some articles',
                articles: articles
            });
        }
    });
});

//start server at the port
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is up and listening at the port 3000'));
```

In the file above I connect to the db, and the connection is successful.

In app.js I reference my model file (article.js):

```
//bring in mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//create an article schema
let articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

let Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);
module.exports = Article;
```

and when I try to access the '/' route, I get an error of

> ReferenceError: Acticle is not defined
>       at app.get (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/app.js:43:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel
>   Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel
>   Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at expressInit (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel
>   Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>       at /media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at query (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/media/domanski/Domanski/1_Tel
>   Ran/webinars_2018/20181014/nodebase_mongo/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

Does anyone has an Idea what do I do wrong?

Comment: You have `Acticle` spelling mistake.

Comment: flagging for closure because typo

Comment: yes, guys, thanks, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues there,

1. Typo in app.js

> Acticle.find() should be Article.find()

2. In article.js(model), you should use the **new** keyword to define a new schema.

   let articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({});

should be replaced with

```
let articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // your schema
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spelling mistake.

```
Acticle.find({}, (err, articles) => {});
```

**Should be**

```
Article.find({}, (err, articles) => {});
```